# Does SemaphoreSlim's Wait(Int32) method return immediately when passed zero?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, concurrency, semaphore

In the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx) for Semaphore's WaitOne(Int32) method, it says that giving it a value of zero will cause the method to return immediately without waiting for a slot to open up. The documentation for the [SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289488%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) version does not say the same thing. Does SemaphoreSlim share this behavior?

I'm not sure how to guarantee the timing to test this myself.

Comment: Yes.  A timeout of 0 really means "no timeout".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If passed a timeout of 0 then `SemaphoreSlim.Wait` will always attempt to acquire a slot before returning, it just won't wait around for one for longer than a few operations and a `SpinOnce`.

**EDIT: clarification:** This is probably the same apparent behaviour as `Semaphore`. From the documentation for `Semaphore`:

> It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately

However `SemaphoreSlim` does give a slot a chance of opening up once you are in the Wait method, through the use of `SpinOnce`.

(end edit)

Also, `SemaphoreSlim` runs a few operations before attempting to acquire a slot. One of these is a `Monitor.Enter`, so it could wait on other threads at that point who are in the process of waiting or releasing. It will not necessarily, therefore, return immediately.

As far as I know the order of events is:

1. Create a `CancellationTokenRegistration`
2. **If the available slot count is 0**, then `SpinWait.SpinOnce` (or skip this if `NextSpinWillYield` is `true`)
   (*edit: I made this bold to emphasise that step 2 does the same test as step 5, giving it a chance to spin and have a slot become available before the final test and exit*)
3. Call `Monitor.Enter` to enter the lock (the same lock that Release and WaitAsync enters)
4. Increment the internal waitCount by 1
5. **If the available slot count is 0**, decrement waitCount by 1 and Exit the lock, then **return `false`**
6. **If we get to here and there is a free slot**:

   - decrement the available slot count by 1 (implication: acquire the slot)
   - Reset the waitHandle under `AvailableWaitHandle`, if it is being used and the available slot count is now 0 again
   - Decrement waitCount by 1
   - Exit the lock
   - Dispose of the `CancellationTokenRegistration`
   - **return `true`**

(Note that other threads who are using non-zero timeouts intermittently release and acquire the lock used to protect the counters by calling `Monitor.Wait`, so you won't wait forever with a timeout of 0, just for a very short time.)

So `SemaphoreSlim` would not seem to share the exact same 0 timeout behaviour with `Sempahore`, as it does give a slot a chance to open up. (Maybe this is why there is `Semaphore.WaitOne` and `SemaphoreSlim.Wait` - to cause code not to compile when upgrading old code by just changing the instantiation of the Semaphore, and therefore making us check the behaviour).

The article [Semaphore vs. SemaphoreSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't highlight this behaviour, just the fundamental differences between the two.

*Side note:*

Interestingly that reference also states

> [SemaphoreSlim] does *not* support ... the use of a wait handle for synchronization

And yet the documentation for [SemaphoreSlim.AvailableWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim.availablewaithandle.aspx) says differently.